# Printing accelerometer data every 1 second

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am desiging an app that displays gyroscope and accelerometer readings every second. This is the code I use
I have a start button, setting time to current in the OnCreate method.

```
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mSensorManager.registerListener(MainActivity.this, mAccelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(MainActivity.this, mGyroscopeSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

        }
```

And then in onSensorChanged:

```
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (currentTime - time > 1000) {

        time = currentTime;
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {


            case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE: {
                mXGyrValueText.setText(String.format("%1.3f",
                        event.values[SensorManager.DATA_X]));
                mYGyrValueText.setText(String.format("%1.3f",
                        event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Y]));
                mZGyrValueText.setText(String.format("%1.3f",
                        event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Z]));

                break;
            }


            case Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION: {
                mXAccValueText.setText(String.format("%1.3f",
                        event.values[SensorManager.DATA_X]));
                mYAccValueText.setText(String.format("%1.3f",
                        event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Y]));
                mZAccValueText.setText(String.format("%1.3f",
                        event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Z]));


                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

This works fine for gyroscope, however accelerometer readings are updating at random time period. What is the problem? Perhaps, there is a better solution?

Comment: One thing I noticed: you are evaluating the same condition  `if (currentTime - time > 1000)`  for both cases. So maybe your accelerometer events simply don't get through because there was a gyroscope event shortly before they came in?

Comment: No, It is not that. Even if I do it without gyroscope case, it acts the same.